# how to know in the main layout that a ListView has been changed?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Suppose that I have a main layout that has a ListView. This ListView has a custom cursor adapter. When my list change, is there anyway to know,  in the main activity, if my list has been changed?. Inside my custom cursor I call to this.notifyDataSetChanged();. Is there any method that can I use to know when notifyDataSetChanged() has been called?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a [DataSetObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DataSetObserver.html) and register it with your adapter by calling [registerDataSetObserver()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#registerDataSetObserver%28android.database.DataSetObserver%29).

p.s. I strongly suggest that you familiarize yourself with [the Android API Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html). This is a great tool to help you find the classes and methods which are available in the Android API.

Comment: thank you so much!!. That's what I was looking for. Yes, I know about the API reference, but it has so much things that you don't know where to start looking!!. I think with practices you can get to know the API very well. Anyway, today I have learned something new ;) thanks!

Comment: @kiduxa No problem. Learning what is available in the API docs certainly takes time. Good luck with your Android development!